# How to add JSON data as text field in HTML using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch a .txt json data, convert it to.json. And after doing so, to have the data be displayed inside text fields. I have created different id's in HTML for each field but currently stuck on how the data can be presented inside text fields. (I can display the JSON data as needed but not inside text fields.)

JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "shippername": "Ommitted",
        "pucity": "Mississauga",
        "pustate": "New York"
    }
]
```

JS Code:

```
fetch('json.txt')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendData(data);
    })    
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

function appendData(data) {
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("ShipperDetails");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = 'Shipper Name: ' + data[i].shippername  + 'PU City: ' + data[i].pucity;
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
}}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="ShipperDetails">
  <p>Shipper Name</p>
  <p id="shippername"></p>
  <input type='text' placeholder="Shipper Name" id="shippername">
  <p>Pickup City</p>
  <input type='text' placeholder="Pickup City" id="pucity">
  <p>Pickup State</p>
  <input type='text' placeholder="Pickup State" id="pustate">
</div>
```

Comment: What’s wrong with your current example? Do you see any errors?

Comment: <p id="shippername"></p> should not be there. I'm trying to have that data be inside the <input type='text'....id="shippername"> instead.

Is there a way to do so. or should I stick with the <p> function and just style it using css? 

NOTE: JSON data will only be one entry instead of multiple entries (will be extracted from email and stringified separately.

Comment: Select the elements themselves rather than the parent?

Comment: The JSON data is in an array. (0) Is there going to be more than 1 element in this array at a time? If so, it seems like you'll want to repeat almost all of the html you've shown for each element. If this is the case,the html `template` element seems ideal.

Comment: const data = [ //do this in a single file
    {
        "shippername": "Ommitted",
        "pucity": "Mississauga",
        "pustate": "New York"
    }
]

Comment: import { data } from './src/data' // import this where you needs

Comment: function appendData() {
    data.map((data, i) => {
        return <div id="ShipperDetails">
            <p>Shipper Name</p> 
            <p id="shippername"></p> //here is the single value like value={data.shippername}
            <input type='text' value={data.shippername} placeholder="Shipper Name" id="shippername"/>
            <p>Pickup City</p>
            <input type='text' placeholder="Pickup City" id="pucity"/>
            <p>Pickup State</p>
            <input type='text' placeholder="Pickup State" id="pustate"/>
        </div>
    })
}

Comment: <div>
    {
        this.appendData()
    }
</div>

Comment: I think this will helping you to fetch json data from external file...try it thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox: yea, i'll do it that way since it is going to be only 1 array.

Comment: @Sajibsaha Why didn't you type an answer instead?

Comment: @Sajibsaha why not write an answer rather than dumping code in comments?